# Exit ScreenSaver Photo by pressing only a key excluding the mouse movement

Tags: windows-7, command, screensaver, regedit

How to have a ScreenSaver that will exit by pressing only the (escape) key excluding the mouse. Setting a key for exiting the ScreenSaver.

I am using Windows 7.

I wanted to set the escape key only (except the mouse movement) for exiting the ScreenSaver. I am using "ScreenSaverPhoto" and I wanted to have a continuous ScreenSaver display for my computer, so that even by pressing any key or mouse moving won't disturb/exit the ScreenSaver display.

I have search multiple times in google and stackoverflow and some other websites, but I found no solution.